Command works in CMD but not in C#
I am facing a trouble in executing a command in c# process with arguments. The command runs well in CMD but it returns no result with System.NotSupported Exception.
string pdfkPath = @"C:\Dummy Projects\TestBCL\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\pdftk.exe";
var cmd = @"D:\TestBCL\Sample.pdf dump_data | findstr NumberOfPages";

var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = pdfkPath,
        Arguments = cmd,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();

var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

The below command gives proper result in CMD, but no luck in C# code.
pdftk.exe D:\TestBCL\Sample.pdf dump_data | findstr NumberOfPages

I tried to use various solution including using /C /K. Or try to escape the Pipe | Operator but not getting any help with them.

I think you need to read the StandardOutput of the proc.StartInfo instead.

^^ Means: you need to code that pipe. Read StdOut from "pdftk.exe  dump_data" and write it to "findstr NumberOfPages", then read the output of that.

Maybe you could code that line into a batch file and execute that?

@RetiredNinja - not working

@Fildor - let me try... but can't use one more file reference for a batch command..

Specify WorkingDirectory, default is c:\Windows\System32. You also need to wait for the process to complete before reading the output. Process.Start starts the process and does not wait for anything.

try adding RedirectStandardError = true. Also read the error var error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Read error output   and after everything proc.WaitForExit();

The question shows a misunderstanding of what even the CMD batch does. The | pipe isn't an argument. It's a shell operator that passes the results of the pdftk program to the venerable findstr program carried over from the MS-DOS days. Process runs one process. You can't pass the other process as an argument. You can pass one process's StandardOutput to another's StandardInput BUT you can do the same thing as findstr if not more if you use eg a Regex on output. Or you can read the output one line at a time with StreamReader and use eg line.Contains("NumberOfPages")
